# Writing Python's List or Dictionary into CSV file (Row containing More than One Column)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am just starting up Python!!

i want to make a CSV file where i have a dictionary and i want to print each member of it in its own column in the same row.

like i have an array of dictionaries and i want each row to represent one of them and each column of each row to represent an item inside.

```
import csv


"... we are going to create an array of dictionaries and print them all..."

st_dic = []

true = 1

while true:
    dummy = input("Please Enter name, email, mobile, university, major")
    x = dummy.split(",")

    if "Stop" in x:
        break

    dict ={"Name":x[0],"Email":x[1],"Mobile":x[2],"University":x[3],"Major":x[4]}
    st_dic.append(dict)

f2 = open("data.csv" , "w")

with open("data.csv", "r+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in st_dic:
        writer.writerow([item["Name"], item["Email"], item["Mobile"] , item["University"] , item["Major"]])
    f.close()
```

the thing i output now is a row which contains the data in the first dictionary, i just want them seperated, each in its own column within its row.

Answer (score 1):

It is surprising there are so many questions here that try to fill in some data in `while` loop and `input()` command. In all the fairness, this is not python best use case.

Imagine you had the dictionary just filled in your code:

```
dict1 = {'name': "Kain", 'email': 'make_it_up@something.com'} 
dict2 = {'name': "Abel", 'email': 'make_it_up2@otherthing.com'}
dict_list = [dict1, dict2]
```

After that you can export to csv easily:

```
import csv 
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['name', 'email'], lineterminator='\n')
    w.writeheader()
    for row in dict_list:  
        w.writerow(row)
```

Note there are many questiona about `csv` module on SO 
as well as there are [examples in documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples).